# Is a larger table or two small tables (one-to-one) for performance?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, rdbms

To optimize reading-queries: it is better to slipt the data into two tables (one-to-one) or create only one table with many more columns?

**(Case 1)**

Table: Movie_info

- rating
- Actors
- directors
- description
- posters

Table: Movies

- id
- title
- subtitle
- url
- movieInfo_id

**(Case 2)**

Table: Movies

- id
- title
- subtitle
- url
- rating
- Actors
- directors
- description
- posters

Which division of the data is more powerful reading-queries?

Comment: What do you need to read most? Why do you think splitting would help with anything?

Comment: if you go with option 1, the actors are related to a directors or posters? if you go with option 2, you can only have one posters per movie?

Comment: @BookOfZeus - he is saying there is a 1-to-1 correlation.

Comment: @oded sorry, i think this should be more normalized but that's my opinion

Comment: You're saying there's a 1::1 relationship between "Movie" and "actors" or "posters".  Note the plural: "s".  There are MULTIPLE actor(s), MULTIPLE DIFFERENT poster(s) and (possibly!) multiple different director(s) ("West Side Story: Robert Wise and Jerome Robbins").  "Movie_info" that pertains to exactly one movie should NOT be in a separate table (Case 1 is incorrect).  But data associated with multiple different movies (e.g. "actors") should have a different table.  IMHO...

Comment: @user1028100 you should learn about database normalization/optimization. For your question, 1 table vs 2 tables will result almost the same but if you want maintainability good luck. Having 1 table for everything IS NOT the solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Real performance depends on the real size of your tables but the rule of thumb:

> "Denormalization (one table instead of two in this particular example)
>   always increases read performance since you need not to join the
>   relations."

Of course, when one-to-one joins are used joined relation can be precomputed by the database system but that's another story.

So simply, one table is better.

Comment: WRONG: one table design = bad. in this case, if you have 25 actors using 1 table, how would you do it? same for poster? subtitle? a good normalize database schema will always perform good when it's optimize and indexed correctly. I run an hosting company and 4 of my biggest clients have approx 10 tera bytes of data, one of them runs a query **under 1 second** with 4 left joins and each tables has over 300 millions of rows. maybe 1 table will be faster than 2 (like 0.01 seconds faster) but maintainability and efficiency of data, not at all